# append char label HTML with overfloat

Tags: html, label

I have a big label, so I use

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

but I need put a "*" on end,

> **this is my full label without CSS ***

turn it in

> **this is... ***

how I do it?

Answer (score -1):

You could add * in a separate element ( perhaps span ) inside your label that is floated to the right. Also increase or add padding-right to the label to make room for it.